# How to add group by to part of string with different length

Tags: sql, group-by, group

I want to group by city when the address column shows as follows.
The city names are not of the same length nor do they contain the same delimiter.

How do I place a group by on the city name in the address portion.

```
Address          order id
Toronto - 123    1
Toronto  3333    2
Ottawa - 222     3
Missouri  4444   1
```

Comment: Are the city names always followed by a space (blank) character? you can find its location. The actual function to find it depends on the rdbms product you are using: add the tag of the rdbms you are using to your question. Also, what do you mean by 'group by', what is the expected output?

Comment: Add some city names having a space character to your sample data, e.g. Los Angeles, Rio de Janeiro.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: can you share your expected output table?

Comment: The city names are always followed by the remaining address, they don't have the same delimiter in every case, they could be followed by colon without space. 
The expected output should be group by city name(only) to count(orderid)